# Why this multiline for/in/do doesn't work in a batch?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

To help my kid learn the most common colors, I made this batch (it's Windows 7 but I suppose it's the same on another Windows version):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (^
black ^
blue ^
green ^
gray ^
orange ^
pink ^
red ^
#82461F ^
#7E287E ^
white ^
yellow ^
) do ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=%%a:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
```

Pretty straightforward: the `for` loop runs every `ffplay` command one at a time, filling my 16:9 screen with a single color until the kid recognizes the color and names it well; then I press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit that instance of `ffplay` and the next color is displayed.

I break the command so I can have every color value in a line to easily mix the lines when I need it in order to avoid a specific order to be learned.

But it just doesn't work. If I get right from these two questions...

- [Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch
  (.bat)
  file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-windows-vista-batch-bat-file)
- [How to split double quoted line into multiple lines in Windows batch
  file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643376/how-to-split-double-quoted-line-into-multiple-lines-in-windows-batch-file)

... since every `^<new line>` disappears from the final command, my batch is equivalent to the command line interpreter single line...

```
for %a in (black blue green gray orange pink red saddlebrown violet white yellow ) do ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=%a:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
```

... which, needless to say, works perfectly.

What it does work is beginning the last line with **a space**. But, in spite of finding a way to make the batch work, the question remains. Why is it necessary **that space**? Or, what am I missing from the answers to the listed questions?

Edit:
  #82461F==brown
  #7E287E==violet
My wife wasn't convinced of how these two named colors looked on our display.

Edit:
For reference, the final working batch (thanks all), with colors alphabetically ordered and without unnecessary carets and spaces:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
black
blue
#82461F %= brown %
gray
green
orange
pink
red
#7E287E %= violet %
white
yellow
) do ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=%%a:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
```

Comment: What space are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv Are you asking why the space after `yellow )` like that is needed or some other space? That space actually is not needed after the `yellow` value and just before the `)` bracket in that part of the loop. Furthermore, as per LotPings answer, you can actually start `black` on the line beneath `for %%a in (` if you wanted to and it should work just fine that way rather than having `for %%a in (black` on that same line but omit the caret symbols for sure. I'm still a little confused but maybe that will help or add on for the answer by LotPings for you.

Comment: I was adding the space at the end of every line because I thought it was necessary to separate the values between parenthesis (just as when you write the command in one line). I didn't know that the `for` command could be split in several lines (I use it since W2K and never found that out). So, all I was doing was using carets to split a one-line `for`. I put the space even in the last value because I intended to shuffle the lines later on and I (wrongly) thought it would fail then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit all the line continuation chars `^` they aren't neccessary,
but as the lines following start in the first column this is interpreted as escaping the first char of the following line - not what you itended I guess.

That doesn't harm for letters, but escaping the closing parentheses is a different thing.
The following batch echoes only the command for testing purposes:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (black
blue
green
gray
orange
pink
red
#82461F
#7E287E
white
yellow) do echo ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=%%a:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
```

Sample output:

```
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=black:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=blue:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=green:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=gray:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=orange:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=pink:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=red:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=#82461F:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=#7E287E:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=white:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
ffplay -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=yellow:160x90:d=3,format=rgb24 -fs
```

Comment: I didn't know you don't need the carets, not even spaces between words (the newlines are enough). Now that you mention, I notice that in one answer they say that carets at the end of line deletes both the caret and the newline AND escapes the next character. So this was the problem: if you escape the closing parentheses, it loses its meaning in the command and it fails semantically. Interestingly enough, with `echo on` in the wrong version, you don't see **any command at all** (you would expect to see the wrong command and then the complaint of the interpreter).